My moveable image is not being able to move in kivy
I just started using kivy to make apps with python, and I am creating a kivy comic maker where you need to drag items onto the screen. However, when I try to when running, I can't move the image needing to be dragged. I have tried many things to solve this issue, but nothing works. I want the draggable image to be in a scrollable library of images, but I can't even drag it in the first place.
Here is my code:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

kivy.require('1.9.0')

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScrn>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    RelativeLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            
            Label:
                text: "Drag 'N Draw Comic Maker"
                font_size: 85
                color: 0.12, 0.38, 0.80
            Button:
                text: "Start"
                font_size: 32
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                size_hint: (0.25, 0.4)
                on_press: root.manager.current = "saves"
            Widget:
                size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            Button:
                text: "Gallery"
                font_size: 32
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
                size_hint: (0.25, 0.4)
                on_press: root.manager.current = "gallery"
<Gallery>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    RelativeLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Gallery"
            font_size: 128
            color: 0.12, 0.38, 0.80
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.25}
        Label:
            text: "coming soon"
            font_size: 32
            color: 0.12, 0.38, 0.80
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "menu"
                    
<SaveScrn>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            text: "SAVES"
            font_size: 64
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "menu"
        Button:
            text: "New"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: (0.375, 0.375)
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.9, "left": 1}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "create"
        Button:
            text: "Empty"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: (0.375, 0.375)
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.9, "right": 1}
        Button:
            text: "Empty"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: (0.375, 0.375)
            pos_hint: {"bottom": 0.9, "left": 1}
        Button:
            text: "Empty"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: (0.375, 0.375)
            pos_hint: {"bottom": 0.9, "right": 1}
                    
<CreateScrn>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Create"
            font_size: 32
            color: 0.12, 0.38, 0.80
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.45}
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: (0.1, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "saves"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            RelativeLayout:
            CustomScrollView:
                size_hint: (0.3, 1)
                pos_hint: {'right': 1}
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1  # Black color
                    Line:
                        rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
                        width: 1.5
                MoveableImage:
                    source: 'stickman-removebg-preview.png'
                    size: 100, 100
                    pos: 500, 500  # Start from the border
                    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
                    drag_timeout: 100000000000000000
                    drag_distance: 0
""")

class CustomScrollView(ScrollView):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # pass the touch event to children
        for child in self.children:
            if child.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
                return True
        return super(CustomScrollView, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    pass
    

class MenuScrn(Screen):
    pass

class Gallery(Screen):
    pass

class SaveScrn(Screen):
    pass

class CreateScrn(Screen):
    pass

class ComicMaker(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScrn(name="menu"))
        sm.add_widget(Gallery(name="gallery"))
        sm.add_widget(SaveScrn(name="saves"))
        sm.add_widget(CreateScrn(name="create"))
        sm.current = "menu"
        return sm

comicMaker = ComicMaker()
comicMaker.run()


Don't have an answer for you, but perhaps some hints. The ScrollView uses mouse events for its scrolling, so that may interfere with your dragging. Perhaps changing the ScrollView scroll_type to ["bars"] might help. Another point is that if you are dragging an object from a container, you will need to remove the object from the container and add it to a higher level container (probably the CreatScrn in your code). Hope this helps.
